# JavaScript - How do I exclude elements from an object?

Tags: javascript, key

I have an object `MainObject`, but I would like to exclude and map some of the keys before returning it to the user. However, I do not know all of the keys since I use the `...{}` operator to let the user add some custom data into the object.

*My code looks something like this:*

```js
var UserData = {Id: 123, Name: "Hello World"}
var Data = {Main: "Data", Secret: "Data1", Math: 22, ...UserData}
// Resulting Object Keys [Main, Secret, Math, Id, Name]
// Wanted Object {Main, Math/2, Id, Name}
var result = ?
```

What I would like to do is to exclude the `Secret` property and devide the `Math` property by 2, while keeping the Data object intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const { Secret, ...result } = Data;

result.mathDivBy2 = function() { return this.Math/2; }

console.log(result);
```

To get Math/2 you call `result.mathDivBy2();`

If you want more convenient access, instead of a function, you can define getter for `result` object:

```
Object.defineProperty(result, 'mathDivBy2', {
  get: function() { return this.Math/2; } 
});
```

and use it like any other property: `result.mathDivBy2`

Answer (score 2):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your object as follows and assign `Math / 2` after destructuring:

```js
var UserData = { Id: 123, Name: "Hello World" };
var Data = { Main: "Data", Secret: "Data1", Math: 22, ...UserData };
var { Secret, ...result } = Data;
result.Math /= 2;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To remove the `Secret` key-value pair, all you need to do is to do `delete Data.Secret`.
2. To divide `Data.Math` by 2, you can do `Data.Math /= 2`.

```js
const UserData = {
  Id: 123,
  Name: "Hello World"
}
const Data = {
  Main: "Data",
  Secret: "Data1",
  Math: 22,
  ...UserData
}

// Delete `Data.Secret`
delete Data.Secret;

// Divide `Data.Math`
Data.Math /= 2;

console.log(Data);
```

However, if you are not too sure the shape of `UserData` coming in and want to make sure that only whitelisted key-value pairs are allowed, you will have to define the allowed keys and then iterate through your entire object to remove unwanted keys:

```js
const UserData = {
  Id: 123,
  Name: "Hello World"
}
const Data = {
  Main: "Data",
  Secret: "Data1",
  Math: 22,
  ...UserData
}

// Whitelist allowed object keys
const allowedKeys = ['Main', 'Math', 'Id', 'Name'];
Object.keys(Data).forEach(key => {
  if (!allowedKeys.includes(key))
    delete Data[key];
});

// Divide `Data.Math`
Data.Math /= 2;

console.log(Data);
```

Comment: This is not quite what i asked for, since this will not keep the Data object intact

Answer (score 0):

just delete it...

```
var UserData = {Id: 123, Name: "Hello World"}
var Data = {Main: "Data", Secret: "Data1", Math: 22, ...UserData}
var forexclude  = Object.assign({}, Data); //for cloning object
var excluded = delete forexclude.Secret; // for remove Secret

alert(JSON.stringify(forexclude, null, 4));
alert(JSON.stringify(excluded, null, 4));

// Resulting Object Keys [Main, Secret, Math, Id, Name]
// Wanted Object {Main, Math/2, Id, Name}
var result = ?
```

Comment: `delete` was introduced in JavaScript 1.2 in June 1997.

Comment: Refering to the last sentance of my question "while keeping the Data object intact"

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep the Data object `intact`. Its better to `deep clone` it first and then remove unwanted keys and update the value as required.

```js
var UserData = {Id: 123, Name: "Hello World"}
var Data = {Main: "Data", Secret: "Data1", Math: 22, ...UserData};
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));
delete result["Secret"];
result["Math"] /= 2;

console.log(result);
//Data will remains as it is
console.log(Data);
```